# Granting users.read.all permission to all users in the domain

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was told by one of the engineers at Microsoft that in order to display the jobtitle field, using users method in REST, I need an admin permission. I would appreciate if someone can answer exactly what steps the domain administrator needs to take in order to give user.read.all permission to all users in the domain that will run the graph query. I would appreciate if anyone can provide detailed step by step instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan's link took care of the problem.
In the link the below sample link was the answer. Instead of the word "common", I have replaced it with the tenant ID as shown below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id from azure ad}/adminconsent?
client_id={application client id}
&state={can be anything. I used the same as the redirect url}
&redirect_uri={URL that exactly appears in the app application portal}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `user.read.all`, you will need to get administrative consent from the organization before a regular user can sign-in to your application.

To do this, you'll first need to have them go through the “Admin Consent” workflow. This workflow requires an administrator but once complete any users of your application will have “admin consent” to the restricted scope.

For example, you would normally you would then authenticate users by redirecting them to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?<your params>.`

Since this scope requires an Admin however, you fist need to obtain consent by first having an Admin authenticate by redirecting them to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?<yours params>.`

Once an Admin grants consent, normal users will be able to use OAUTH to authenticate.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I get the concept. but what goes in to <yours params> section? Could you be specific on this?

Comment: The same params you are sending to the authorize link today (appid, scopes you want, etc.). If you just reuse the same query you may have some extra params but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint for details